# Karate DSL - using Java packages in feature files

Tags: karate

I'm calling JVM classes in karate feature file using Java Inte rop. It works well, but I have number of classes (about 25) in java package and would like to call/define all classes in the package. Is there any possibilities/approach?

Currently I'm defining 25 Java Inte rop variables in Background and using in Scenarios.  Any idea to define package itself and use corresponding classes in scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a better suggestion. Use a single Java class, and have multiple static helper methods on it.

Then you just need to init a single variable.

```
* def utils = Java.type('com.mycompany.MyUtils')
* def result = utils.doWork()
* utils.doSomeOtherWork('message', 500)
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for the input.
I have been using your suggested way for calling Java and JS methods/functions in feature files and works well. 
This method is grate if we have few java classes (with many methods). But if we have java many classes and there is no option of merging into few classes. Currently a long list of def used in background to refer each class.
Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Umeshkandhalu yes there is an option. write one more Java class that delegates to these many classes. standard Java fundamentals. please also mark this answer as "accepted", thanks.