# Failed to select options in drop-down using select class in karate bdd

Tags: karate

I have tried to locate a drop-down using karate framework with the help of select class but it's not getting detected.But with the same locator I am able to select option in drop down using serenity bdd. The syntax which I followed is below.
And select ('select[name= locator, 'visible text']')

Can anyone please check this and let me know, is there any way to create custom method in karate bdd and how can we call a method from a java class to a feature file in karate UI Automation?.

Comment: and you can call java code like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51349903/143475 and PLEASE read the docs, thanks.